# Weird Render transparency artifact

Tags: rendering, mesh, blender-internal-render-engine, artifacts

As you can see in the picture below, I have just rendered a frame of an animation and a triangular piece is missing. You can download the .blend and try it for yourself - it happens on some frames(like 24 in the example) and on others it doesn't, from what I've seen about every 4th frame.

Interesting to note is the fact that the fog, which I have strengthened to see the effect, still renders correctly, so it's only the plane with the image

[image: blender]

[image]

EDIT: It went away after moving the image about 25 more units away from the camera - no idea why, and I would still highly appreciate suggestions.

Comment: probably the issue is related to the clip distance and or some form of z-fighting or z-precision

Comment: I'm going to suggest you submit this as a [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/). I see both planes breaking and separating allowing the background through, each frame produces the glitch with different values, adjusting the camera clip_start by 0.1 shows or hides the result at different values, similar with the focal length at 0.01 steps, cutting another edge through the image plane the opposite way to the break hides it while cutting it the same way as the break leaves it there.

Comment: which OS and graphics card are you using? So that I can write a more specific bug report

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a very old known issue with Blender Internal renderer (caused by numerical imprecision), see e.g. this [nine years old report](https://developer.blender.org/T18056).

Workaround of triangulating the buggy mesh (using e.g. the relevant modifier) seems to be working quite nicely, when that issue shows up.